# 406 error while mocking File Download REST API using MockMVC

Tags: spring, rest, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I am implementing a REST API using Spring framework, which returns

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(new InputStreamResource(myInputStream),
                responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```

REST API is declared as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE })
```

While writing unit test for this API, I am using MockMVC like below:

```
final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = 
new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
messageConverter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
messageConverter.getObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

this.mockMvc = 
MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController)
.setMessageConverters(messageConverter)
.apply(new RestDocumentationConfigurer()
.withScheme("https").withHost("localhost")
.withPort(443)).build();
```

And my Test case looks like this:

```
mockMvc.perform(
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders
.get(restUri))
.andExpect(
org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers
.status().isOk())
.andDo(document("myApi")).andReturn();
```

But I am getting status as error 406.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<406>
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail
```

What I am missing here?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You inject instance of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to `MockMvcBuilders` which can't deal with converting classes inheriting from `Resource`. All you need to do is add `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` to your test specification:

```
MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(myController)
.setMessageConverters(messageConverter, new ResourceHttpMessageConverter())
```

Answer (score 0):

Status code 406 means "Not Acceptable", which indicates that the server is missing a header specifying an accepted content type. You'll need to include that in your mockMvc call.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too as
 'andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE))' 
but then it gives error as content type not set. 

I tried setting content type in my REST API response header too but that also didn't work.

Comment: That's not what I said. What you're doing is setting up an expectation on the response. You need to set up a precondition on the request: call `accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET‌​_STREAM)` on the `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder`, so that the appropriate accept header is populated.

Comment: Yes, tried that too but still getting 406 error. mockMvc.perform(
    get(restUri).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)).andExpect(status().isOk())